# in bash find all files in flat directory that don't exist in another directory tree

Tags: file, bash, find, not-exists, directory-tree

I have many files in a directory `A`.

Some of those files exist in a directory tree with sub-directories `B/B1`, `B/B2`, `B/B3`, `B/B4`, ...
Note that some files have spaces in their names.

For example:

in directory `A`:

- there's a file named `A/red file.png`
- there's another named `A/blue file.png`

  and, in directory tree `B`:
- there's a file named `B/small/red file.png`

  In this example, I would like a script to tell me that the file `blue file.png` does not exist in the directory `B`.

How can I write a script that will list all the files in `A` that are not found under the directory tree `B`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# A
# ├── blue file.png
# └── red file.png
# B
# └── small
#     └── red file.png

$ comm -23 <( find A -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq ) <( find B -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq )
blue file.png
```

If your `find` lacks `-printf`, you can try:

```
comm -23 <( find A -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq ) <( find B -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq )
```

Comment: Thanks. My "find" doesn't seem to have -printf, so I used -print instead. That shouldn't make any difference, right?

Comment: Hang on. Something's not working. I'm still getting files in the result that exist in both A and B.

Comment: Okay. Maybe it's the -printf. When I use -print instead, I get the whole filename, including the directory. If -printf '%f' gives me the file's basename, I'll accept the answer, but how would I adapt this script to a "find" that doesn't have -printf?

Comment: Try: `comm -23 <( find A -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq ) <( find B -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq )`

Comment: What OS / Version are you using?

Comment: The -exec basename {} worked. What's that "\;"? I'm on a Mac with Snow  Leopard, but not sure how to tell what version my shell is, nor its tools.

Comment: The `-exec` option runs a command on each matching file , the `{}` is replaced by the file path and the command is terminated with a semicolon. The backslash before the semicolon is to prevent your shell from interpetetting it as shell syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is version which can cope with all filenames, including ones containing newlines:

```
comm -z23 <(find dir1 -type f -printf '%f\0' | sort -uz) <(find dir2 -type f -printf '%f\0' | sort -uz) | xargs -0 printf '%s\n'
```